# recurrent function sequence uniformly converging to $x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_1(x)\geq 0$ for any $x\in [0;A]$ and let $f_{n+1}(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{f_n(t)}dt$. Prove, that the sequence $f_n(x)$ uniformly converge to $x^2$ in $[0;A]$.

Comment: Hint: use Dini theorem

Comment: I cannot even show pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)$. Expand the hint, please, if you can.